# What verb should I use for "match"? E.g. Please match the answers

Tags: translation, verbs, phrase-requests

I'm writing some instructions on a worksheet, and I want to translate the English instructions into Japanese.  I'm trying to say something along the lines of

> Please match the genre in English to the explanation in Japanese.

I do not need to be very specific because I will be explaining this out loud and the written instructions are just a little guidance if they didn't quite understand.

Here's an example of what the paper would look like.

____1. Rock
____2. Jazz
____3. Classical

A. (ジャンル説明)
B. (ジャンル説明)
c. (ジャンル説明)

I am having difficulty finding the correct verb to use for "match."

Google translate suggests **合{あ}わせる**

> 英語のジャンルを日本語の説明に合わせてください。

Or **一致{いっち}する**

> 日本の説明に英語のジャンルと一致してください。

After searching jisho.org, I also agree that these two verbs are the closest in meaning.  But there were no example sentences for either word that really matched up with what I'm trying to say.  So I'm still unsure if the usage makes proper sense.

I make worksheets like this all the time, so I was hoping for a good verb to use for various situations, not just this one specifically.  But perhaps the English word "match" has far more uses than any Japanese equivalent.

Comment: 「ジャンル」って言葉を使わないとだめですか？　学校のテストでは、「１～３（の語）の説明として最も適切なものを、下のA～C（の中）から（それぞれ）選びなさい。」とか、「１～３（の語）の説明として最も適切なものを選択肢（の中）から選び、それぞれ記号で答えなさい。」とかいう感じで書くことが多いですが。

Comment: 「ジャンル」を使う必要はありません。Chocolateさんの答えも使えるでしょう。ありがとうございます！

Comment: The examples I gave above might sound a bit too much like formal exams... so for instructions in a worksheet for 小学生 (and maybe for 中学生 too) I think you could instead say like 「１～３（の語）の説明（としてよいもの）を、A～Cか‌​ら選びましょう。」「１～３（の語）‌​の説明を、選択肢から選びましょう。」... （すみません、プロフ見たらALTって書いていらっしゃったので。。）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most natural wording is:

> 英語のジャンル**と**対応する日本語の説明**を**選んでください。
>   Choose the Japanese explanation that corresponds to each English genre.
>   <sub>(対応する = to correspond)</sub>

If you mean drawing lines between words on paper, the set phrase for that is **線で結ぶ** (literally "connect with lines").

> 英語のジャンル**と**対応する日本語の説明**を**線で結んでください。

Another option that would work in both cases is 対応づける, which is a transitive verb:

> 英語のジャンル**と**対応する日本語の説明**を**対応づけてください。

But this sounds stiff, vague and less common to me.

英語のジャンル**と**対応する is interchangeable with 英語のジャンル**に**対応する.

---

一致させる and 合わせる do *not* work whatsoever, because they mean "to deform/move/modify something so that it will align with something else", which is not what you need for now. Also note that 一致する is intransitive, so 日本語の解説に一致してください would mean something weird like "Please become one with the Japanese explanation", if it means anything.

Comment: I have updated my question to show an example of what kind of matching will be on the paper.

Comment: @KumaAra Okay, then I need to revise my answer :) Moment, please.

Comment: You might also try 一番相応しい答え１つ or 最もよいものを1つ